# Why does the € symbol render as a "0" in HTML using Phoenixframework

Tags: html, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to insert the € symbol as a string in a template and it render as a `0`. I tried to use symbols and HTML entities without success. I also used `raw` and again no success.
My html page as a `<meta charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: Can you show a live example?

Comment: I just edited the title because I think this is specific to the Phoenixframework. I didn't include it in the title because I got some downvotes earlier because I did that (Stackoverflow experts say tags are the ONLY thing needed but apparently that's not true...)

Comment: OK, but can you show a live example? It's likely to vastly improve the quality of answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else found it (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phoenix-talk/AFCjgp9-CAg): the non-standard font I'm using doesn't have the euro symbol!
Solved.

Answer (score -1):

Tryed one those?

```
<?php echo "&euro;'"; ?>

<p> &euro; </p>

<p> &#8364; </p>

<p> &#x20AC; </p>
```

Or this?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: I tried that. I just edited the title because I think this is specific to the Phoenixframework. I didn't include it in the title because I got some downvotes earlier because I did that (Stackoverflow experts say tags are the ONLY thing needed but apparently that's not true...)

Answer (score -2):

You can try it with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or just use those entities: `&euro;`, `&#8364;`, `&#x20AC;`. Do not forget the `;` after the hex/decimal value.

Download the Bootstrap stylesheet and bind it to your site and just search what is the exact class for euro. Done.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Don't you think it's a bit overkill to include the entirety of Bootstrap for *one* character?